# What is the correct syntax to refer to a TWIG file

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to refer to a TWIG file in symfony 2 project.

Twig file can be referred from controller or view.

the syntax that is use is:

```
SomeBundle:SomeController:SomeTemplate.html.twig
```

*for example: AcmeDemoBundle:Hello:index.html.twig*

other allowed syntax is:

```
SomeBundle:SomeController/SomeFolder:SomeTemplate.html.twig
```

*for example: AcmeDemoBundle:Hello/Crud:index.html.twig*

What is the recommanded syntax ? Are there other syntax ?

Comment: Just out of interest, what's wrong with the ones you've put that make you feel the need to use a different one?

Comment: I would say that most people use the first syntax

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you use subnamespaces to group controllers. For example, you could have the public and admin sections in your app. Then your structure could look like this:

- `AppBundle`

  - `Controller`

    - `Admin`

      - `UserController`
    - `UserController`

In that case you would refer to a view of the public controller as:

```
AppBundle:User:list.html.twig
```

And to a view of the admin controller as:

```
AppBundle:Admin/User:list.html.twig
```

So, it's not about which syntax is preferred, but which one solves your problem.